# How to properly use a directory to upload an image using PHP/MySQL on Linux

Tags: php

I'm trying to upload an image using PHP and MySQL on Linux however the directory I'm using in my code doesn't seem to work properly. My friend working on the project using Windows is using the same code but with a Windows directory and it's working.

Here's the code:

```
if(isset($_POST['upload'])){

echo "test :";
print_r($_FILES);
echo "test 2";

$target="/home/tempus/Bureau/public_html/project/Images/".basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
$connexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","Password","projetDB");

if($connexion){

    echo "<br>";
    echo $target;
    echo "<br>";
    $image=$_FILES['image']['name'];
    $pseudo=$_SESSION['pseudo'];
    $commentaire=$_POST['commentaire'];
    if(empty($image)!=true);
    $req="insert into IMAGES (commentaire,image,pseudo) values('$commentaire','$image','$pseudo')";
    $resultat=mysqli_query($connexion,$req);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$target)){
    $message="Image sent !";
}
else{
    echo $target;
    $message="error ";
    }
}
else{
    echo "Connection error";
}
```

HTML :

```
<form action="propositions.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="propositions.css">
    <fieldset class="Formulaire"><legend><h1>Formulaire </h1></legend>
        <p>Veuillez respecter les regles du <abbr title="Pas de contenu offensant">site :</abbr></p>
        <input type="file" name="image" required="">
<div>
<textarea placeholder="Commenter votre image ..." cols="40" rows="5" name="commentaire"></textarea>
</div>
    <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Valider" ><a href="galerie.php"></a>
</fieldset>
```

Edit:

I'm adding more informations to my post.

Here's the error log:

```
PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpEdnzM0' to '/...'
```

Comment: pretty sure its an permissions problem. check your target-directory for write permissions

Comment: Apart from permissions, linux is case-sensitive for path, while windows is not.

Comment: Yea I googled and a lot of people were having issues with the permissions. I think I granted the necessary ones. Really messed me up so I sadly went for the 777 solution. Still nothing ...

Comment: I added more infos about my case. Maybe a problem with tmp's rights?